# Layouts in Ember

Tags: ember.js

What is the preferred way to have application layouts in Ember 2.0? I would think through components, but they are not yet routable. We used to use views, but those have been deprecated.

Thoughts?

Comment: If you were using application view and can't move off of views, you can try using [ember-legacy-views](http://emberobserver.com/addons/ember-legacy-views) which should be supported until routable components are released.

Comment: Another option would be to simply use components in place of views-- components can do anything that a view can do, and using the extra 'controller' features of a component is purely optional.

Answer (score 2):

Could you be more specific about what you mean by 'layout'? Taken in the Rails sense, as a sort-of container for the actual page content, you can create composable layouts using matching routes & templates.

To give an example, if we have a call to `Router.map` in our `router.js` like so:

```
Router.map(function() {

  this.route('public', function () {
    this.route('foo');
  });

});
```

and both `app/templates/application.hbs` and `app/public/template.hbs` (assuming you're using pods) look like

```
{{!-- HTML  --}}
<div class='some-container'>
  {{outlet}}
</div>
{{!-- More HTML  --}}
```

Visiting the `public.foo` route will render the contents of `app/public/foo/template.hbs` into the outlet of `app/public/template.hbs` which is itself rendering into the application outlet.

So, you have a system of nested layouts that matches your routing structure.

Does this answer your question?